# How to make a React Stack Snippet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, code-snippets

I'm trying to show my code with Stack Snippets. Could someone tell me what is wrong with this React snippet?

This is the working [Codepen](https://codepen.io/ALL9000/pen/YzeJZda).

```js
import { marked } from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/marked@4.0.16";
//import DOMPurify from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/dompurify@2.3.8";

const sampleText = `# Welcome to my React Markdown Previewer!

## This is a sub-heading...
### And here's some other cool stuff:

Heres some code, \`<div></div>\`, between 2 backticks.

\`\`\`
// this is multi-line code:

function anotherExample(firstLine, lastLine) {
  if (firstLine == '\`\`\`' && lastLine == '\`\`\`') {
    return multiLineCode;
  }
}
\`\`\`

You can also make text **bold**... whoa!
Or _italic_.
Or... wait for it... **_both!_**
And feel free to go crazy ~~crossing stuff out~~.

There's also [links](https://www.freecodecamp.org), and
> Block Quotes!

And if you want to get really crazy, even tables:

Wild Header | Crazy Header | Another Header?
------------ | ------------- | -------------
Your content can | be here, and it | can be here....
And here. | Okay. | I think we get it.

- And of course there are lists.
  - Some are bulleted.
     - With different indentation levels.
        - That look like this.


1. And there are numbered lists too.
1. Use just 1s if you want!
1. And last but not least, let's not forget embedded images:

![freeCodeCamp Logo](https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/images/fcc_secondary.svg)
`;

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    text: sampleText,
  };

  handleChange = (event) => {
    const text = event.target.value;
    this.setState({ text });
  };

  //renderText = (text) => DOMPurify.sanitize(marked(text));
  renderText = (text) => marked(text);
  // On souhaite que les modifications soient enregistrée dans le LocalStorage
  // du navigateur. Ainsi si l'utilisateur rafréchit la page, ses modifications
  // seront sauvegarder.

  // On sauvegarde les modifications
  componentDidUpdate() {
    const { text } = this.state;
    localStorage.setItem('text', text);
  }

  // On réaffiche la sauvegarde lorsque l'App est relancée par le rafréchissement.
  // s'il y à eu du text sauvegardé, je rafiche ce text.
  // Si tout à été supprimé, je remets le sampleText de départ.
  componentDidMount() {
    const text = localStorage.getItem('text');
    if (text) {
      this.setState({ text });
    } else {
      this.setState({ text: sampleText });
    }
  }
  // Vidéo - Anthony Welc - Ch 03 - 05  Du Markdown avec Marked, time 03:44
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-sm-6">
            <textarea
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              className="form-control"
              rows="35"
              value={this.state.text}
            ></textarea>
          </div>
          <div className="col-sm-6">
            <div
              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                __html: this.renderText(this.state.text),
              }}
            ></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 24px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-bootstrap@next/dist/react-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/marked/marked.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A few issues:

- local storage won't work in the snippet sandbox.
- modules are a bit tricky to get right, so I'd use UMD imports.
- the latest version of marked uses `marked.parse()` rather than `marked()`

```js
const sampleText = `# Welcome to my React Markdown Previewer!

## This is a sub-heading...
### And here's some other cool stuff:

Heres some code, \`<div></div>\`, between 2 backticks.

\`\`\`
// this is multi-line code:

function anotherExample(firstLine, lastLine) {
  if (firstLine == '\`\`\`' && lastLine == '\`\`\`') {
    return multiLineCode;
  }
}
\`\`\`

You can also make text **bold**... whoa!
Or _italic_.
Or... wait for it... **_both!_**
And feel free to go crazy ~~crossing stuff out~~.

There's also [links](https://www.freecodecamp.org), and
> Block Quotes!

And if you want to get really crazy, even tables:

Wild Header | Crazy Header | Another Header?
------------ | ------------- | -------------
Your content can | be here, and it | can be here....
And here. | Okay. | I think we get it.

- And of course there are lists.
  - Some are bulleted.
     - With different indentation levels.
        - That look like this.


1. And there are numbered lists too.
1. Use just 1s if you want!
1. And last but not least, let's not forget embedded images:

![freeCodeCamp Logo](https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/images/fcc_secondary.svg)
`;

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    text: sampleText,
  };

  handleChange = (event) => {
    const text = event.target.value;
    this.setState({ text });
  };

  renderText = (text) => DOMPurify.sanitize(marked.parse(text));
  // On souhaite que les modifications soient enregistrée dans le LocalStorage
  // du navigateur. Ainsi si l'utilisateur rafréchit la page, ses modifications
  // seront sauvegarder.

  // On sauvegarde les modifications
  componentDidUpdate() {
    const { text } = this.state;
    //localStorage.setItem('text', text);
  }

  // On réaffiche la sauvegarde lorsque l'App est relancée par le rafréchissement.
  // s'il y à eu du text sauvegardé, je rafiche ce text.
  // Si tout à été supprimé, je remets le sampleText de départ.
  componentDidMount() {
    const text = null;
    //const text = localStorage.getItem('text');
    if (text) {
      this.setState({ text });
    } else {
      this.setState({ text: sampleText });
    }
  }
  // Vidéo - Anthony Welc - Ch 03 - 05  Du Markdown avec Marked, time 03:44
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-sm-6">
            <textarea
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              className="form-control"
              rows="35"
              value={this.state.text}
            ></textarea>
          </div>
          <div className="col-sm-6">
            <div
              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                __html: this.renderText(this.state.text),
              }}
            ></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 24px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/marked/marked.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dompurify/0.7.1/purify.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Here's a React 18 version:

```js
const sampleText = `# Welcome to my React Markdown Previewer!

## This is a sub-heading...
### And here's some other cool stuff:

Heres some code, \`<div></div>\`, between 2 backticks.

\`\`\`
// this is multi-line code:

function anotherExample(firstLine, lastLine) {
  if (firstLine == '\`\`\`' && lastLine == '\`\`\`') {
    return multiLineCode;
  }
}
\`\`\`

You can also make text **bold**... whoa!
Or _italic_.
Or... wait for it... **_both!_**
And feel free to go crazy ~~crossing stuff out~~.

There's also [links](https://www.freecodecamp.org), and
> Block Quotes!

And if you want to get really crazy, even tables:

Wild Header | Crazy Header | Another Header?
------------ | ------------- | -------------
Your content can | be here, and it | can be here....
And here. | Okay. | I think we get it.

- And of course there are lists.
  - Some are bulleted.
     - With different indentation levels.
        - That look like this.


1. And there are numbered lists too.
1. Use just 1s if you want!
1. And last but not least, let's not forget embedded images:

![freeCodeCamp Logo](https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/images/fcc_secondary.svg)
`;

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    text: sampleText,
  };

  handleChange = (event) => {
    const text = event.target.value;
    this.setState({ text });
  };

  renderText = (text) => DOMPurify.sanitize(marked.parse(text));
  // On souhaite que les modifications soient enregistrée dans le LocalStorage
  // du navigateur. Ainsi si l'utilisateur rafréchit la page, ses modifications
  // seront sauvegarder.

  // On sauvegarde les modifications
  componentDidUpdate() {
    const { text } = this.state;
    //localStorage.setItem('text', text);
  }

  // On réaffiche la sauvegarde lorsque l'App est relancée par le rafréchissement.
  // s'il y à eu du text sauvegardé, je rafiche ce text.
  // Si tout à été supprimé, je remets le sampleText de départ.
  componentDidMount() {
    const text = null;
    //const text = localStorage.getItem('text');
    if (text) {
      this.setState({ text });
    } else {
      this.setState({ text: sampleText });
    }
  }
  // Vidéo - Anthony Welc - Ch 03 - 05  Du Markdown avec Marked, time 03:44
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-sm-6">
            <textarea
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              className="form-control"
              rows="35"
              value={this.state.text}
            ></textarea>
          </div>
          <div className="col-sm-6">
            <div
              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                __html: this.renderText(this.state.text),
              }}
            ></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app"))
  .render(<App />);
```

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 24px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/marked/marked.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dompurify/0.7.1/purify.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

See also [How do I create a React Stack Snippet with JSX support?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/how-do-i-create-a-react-stack-snippet-with-jsx-support)